# rgrep default files pattern

Tags: cc-mode, rgrep

How can I modify the default FILES pattern in rgrep for C++ mode?

For C mode the default is `*.[ch]`. For C++, it is `*.cc *.cxx *.cpp *.C *.CC *.c++`.

I would like to change it to `*.cc *.[ch]xx *.[ch]pp *.[CHh] *.CC *.HH *.[ch]++`.

Answer (score 6):

<kbd>M-x</kbd>`customize-variable`<kbd>RET</kbd>`grep-files-aliases` and then use the interface to change the value of this variable.

Alternatively, you could put:

```
(setf (cdr (assoc "cc" grep-files-aliases))
      (assoc "cchh" grep-files-aliases))
```

For future reference, you could have looked up the help for `rgrep` (by typing <kbd>C-h f</kbd>`rgrep`) where it says:

> Recursively grep for REGEXP in FILES in directory tree rooted at DIR.
>   The search is limited to file names matching shell pattern FILES.
>   FILES may use abbreviations defined in `grep-files-aliases`, e.g.
>   entering `ch` is equivalent to `*.[ch]`.

Comment: I had to use `(eval-after-load "grep"
  '(setf (cdr (assoc "cc" grep-files-aliases))
         (cdr (assoc "cchh" grep-files-aliases))))`, because `grep-files-aliases` was void while loading my init file.

Comment: @0x5453 Right, I didn't think `grep` package wouldn't be loaded by default.

Comment: When I add the above to my `init.el` file I get the following message upon using `rgrep`:  `split-string: Wrong type argument: stringp, ("cchh" . "*.cc *.[ch]xx *.[ch]pp *.[CHh] *.CC *.HH *.[ch]++")`