# rgrep default dir pattern to skip

Tags: rgrep

How can I modify list of directories which are omitted by default in `rgrep` command?

When use `C-u` `rgrep` I can see list of directories to skip (mostly version control dirs), but I'd like to add `venv` and `node_modules` to this list. There is a similar question about FILES and `grep-files-aliases` variable (see [rgrep default files pattern](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/17209/rgrep-default-files-pattern)), but I could not find anything similar about DIRs.

Answer (score 2):

It is explained (near the end) in the section [Searching with Grep under Emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Grep-Searching.html) in the Emacs manual.

It can be configured via the `grep-find-ignored-directories` variable (which inherits its default value from `vc-directory-exclusion-list`).

You can add directories via the customize interface (`M-x customize-variable` `grep-find-ignored-directories`) or use `add-to-list` to add extra directories to `grep-find-ignored-directories`.